# Почему не работает связка counter, calc и var?

Tags: css, css3

Сделал связку `calc` и `var`, как [написано](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/calc()) в документации MDN. Хочу её использовать для организации динамической прозрачности элементов, для чего использую `counter`, также в соответствии с [документацией](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Counter_Styles/Using_CSS_counters). Написал код, но переменная `--msgO` не получает никакого значения:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#worldGen {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

#worldMap {
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 17000px;
  height: 8000px;
}

#genLog {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  counter-reset: msg;
}

#genLog p {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#genLog p:nth-last-child(n) {
  --msgC: counter(msg);
  --msgO: calc(1 / var(--msgC));
  opacity: var(--msgO);
  counter-increment: msg;
}

#genLog p::after {
  content: var(--msgC);
}
```

```html
<main id="worldGen">
    <canvas id="worldMap"></canvas>
    <section id="genLog">
      <p>
    Cообщение
    </p>
    <p>
    Cообщение
    </p>
    <p>
    Cообщение
    </p>
    </section>
</main>
```

Если заменить `var(--msgC)` в

```
--msgO: calc(1 / var(--msgC));
```

на статичное число так:

```
--msgO: calc(1 / 2);
```

то всё работает. `var(--msgC)` также возвращает корректное значение, что видно по результатам работы стиля `#genLog p::after`. Не работает только связка `calc` и `var`, описанная в документации, как однозначно рабочая. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `counter` не может использоваться в `calc`.

Comment: @Qwertiy но я ведь использую var, а не сам counter. И проблемы уже на вычислении var, как выяснилось.

Comment: Так у тебя внутри var написан counter.

Comment: @Qwertiy то есть var хранит ссылку, а не значение?

Comment: В css нет понятий ссылок и значений. var подставляется как записан.

Comment: @Qwertiy ясно, жаль, но спасибо. Оформите свои первый и последний комментарии в ответ, и я его  приму.